# Aggregating a joint query into an array

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have a problem trying to come up with a query which would return everything that I need in a single request.
This is our DB schema: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5e4fe6e007a7395d994df445
DB is the heroku postgres, which is version 12 by default

Considering that, I need to be able to return a deck object with all of the user specific details appended to flashcards.
Returned object shape should be something like

```
{
  deck_id,
  deck_name,
  deck_author,
  flashcards:[
    {
      flashcard_id,
      question,
      asnwer,
      mastery(needs to be joined from card_mastery table)
    }
  ],
  tags:[
    array of tags
  ]
}
```

Right now I have the following query built in knex.js:

```
db('deck_tags as dt')
    .rightJoin('decks as d', 'd.id', 'dt.deck_id')
    .leftJoin('flashcards as f', 'f.deck_id', 'd.id')
    .leftJoin('tags as t', 't.id', 'dt.tag_id')
    .select(
      'd.id as deck_id',
      'd.user_id',
      'd.name as deck_name',
      'd.public',
      'd.created_at',
      'd.updated_at',
      db.raw(
        'array_to_json(array_remove(ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT t), NULL)) as tags'
      ),
      db.raw(
        'array_to_json(array_remove(ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT f), NULL)) as flashcards'
      )
    )
    .groupBy(
      'd.id',
      'd.user_id',
      'd.name',
      'd.public',
      'd.created_at',
      'd.updated_at'
    )
    .where({ 'd.id': id })
    .first();
```

The problem seems to be in getting the user specific data into the flashcards array.